# Nothing with quotes seems to work in Java

Tags: java, macos, terminal, osx-mavericks

Everytime I try to do....

```
System.out.println("Hello World");
```

Then it gives an error saying "; expected" 
I am  lost to the point that I want to give up on this . Java seems to work fine in Eclipse and Netbeans but in the Mac Terminal it keeps giving this problem

I even tried this

```
String s = "Hello World";
System.out.println(s);
```

But it gives "illegal character" error on the String s line . HOW IS " \" " AN ILLEGAL CHARACTER!

This problem has started arising since the time I updated to Mavericks

My specifications:

```
JAVA VERSION 
{ 
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
}
```

Running from TERMINAL on OSX MAVERICKS

Comment: Show us all of the code.

Comment: We really do mean ALL the code. The entire file.

Comment: Looks like your file only contains `String s = "Hello world";`. Note: Java is not a script language like Python, where your module can contain just `print("Hello world")` (using Python 3). Please refer to a sane tutorial on Java, like the official one: [Lesson: A Closer Look at the "Hello World!" Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, that's not consistent with the error message. If the file only had that line, the compiler would produce the "class, interface or enum expected" message.

Comment: You likely have an unmatched quote in a preceding line.

Comment: -1 for not submitting code despite requests. You want answers, not just speculation, right?

Comment: @kviiri - that's what my 'vote to close' is for :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it has something to do with your code editor. If you use a simple text editor rather than a code editor, your quote characters might be replaced with similar looking unicode characters that will make your code uncompilable.

Solution: make sure you use an established code editor.

EDIT: As you can see [here](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/compileerrormessages.html#ILLEGALCHARACTER), the "illegal character" error will pop up when you use an invalid Unicode character in the code.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. It is based on speculation, about which you should have asked a question first.

Comment: It's an educated guess based on the error message and the code content description. Feel free to downvote if it proves that I'm wrong.

Comment: No downvote, just remember that the purpose of SO is to provide help to future searchers... so I generally avoid speculation-based answers unless I'm really sure it's right.  See my comment to the OP for an alternative that's at least as likely.

Comment: Noted. I've tried to look for some reference, but couldn't find one quickly. I'm going to go on a limb here (this time in a comment :) ) and say that "illegal character" is displayed only when the parser finds a character that is not part of the accepted set. If it was a missing quote, I believe the error message would have been something like "unterminated string constant".

Comment: Good point. You may well be right, and it would help to include the reason for your hunch in the answer itself.

Comment: I know I am replying late but thank you! This technique really worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Java and had the exact same issue, but I managed to figure it out.

I am following a code example in the text book and although it looked identical it would fail at compile. When I downloaded and copied/pasted the code sample from the publisher into my Example.java file in Text editor it would compile fine, so obviously it was something with my code. When I did an undo and went back to my code it failed again. My code is:

```
/* 
   This is a simple Java program. 

   Call this file Example.java. 
*/ 
class Example { 
  // A Java program begins with a call to main(). 
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    System.out.println("Java drives the Web."); 
  } 
}
```

I installed a different text editor - TextWrangler, set the format to Java at the bottom of the screen, re-wrote the code and it worked fine. I found the quotes in Textedit were slanted and in TextWrangler they were straight.

I don't know enough about it - maybe i had to set the unicode different in textedit or something, but I'm using textWrangler now anyway because it's easier to read the code because it highlights by colour.

Hope it helps.